# Change the @Published object value without triggering the didSet {}?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to reset the   @Published var dicParameters without triggering the didSet closure?

```
@Published var dicParameters: Dictionary<String, String> =
                ["Closed": "false", "Completed": "false", "Pending": "false"]{
        didSet{
            print("...........\(self.dicParameters)")
            loadDemos()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply use a custom method where you could selectively do the following functionality using a boolean check. For Example:

```
func setParameters(_ parameters: [String: String], andLoad load: Bool) {
    dicParameters = parameters
    if load {
        loadDemos()
    }
}
```